# Opening a child window using Javascript that has navigation arrows and ability to add its own tabs

Tags: javascript, window

I am trying to open a bare bones window using window.open(), which is pretty basic and easy to do. I'm concerned here with Chrome running on Mac OSX.

My code:

```
window.open(url, "_account", "scrollbars, resizable");
```

A user asked me to add navigation controls (forward, back, reload), menu bar, status bar, and the ability to add new tabs from the child window... basically he wanted the window to behave like a "normal" browser window.

My code changed to:

```
window.open(url, "_account", "toolbar, scrollbars, resizable, menubar, location, status");
```

This was just me basically adding all of the options I could find to enable everything available. Yet this does not actually bring up the navigation controls or an address bar, or the 'new tab' button. When I checked [mozilla's window.open() page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open), (especially the section describing the 'toolbar' option), I read this:

> If this feature [toolbar] is on, then the new secondary window renders the Navigation Toolbar (Back, Forward, Reload, Stop buttons).

That sounds like it should have done exactly what I want, but I don't see those controls.

So, are child windows prevented by some unchangeable browser policy from having those controls? I don't see on that reference page how to add new tabs, address bar (that I can edit to go to a new location).

Thanks in advance.
 (edited to address James's comment below)

Comment: `_self` makes the url open within the current window.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Apologies, I was simplifying code to try to make question easier. I actually point to a custom target name, like `window.open(url, "_account", ...)`. Would this custom target mess with the window that renders?